How does cross validation work in Prophet?
Imagine I have daily data in pandas dataframe. The date range for my data is 2022-01-01 to 2024-03-31. I want to do univariate time series forecasting using Prophet library and I want to perform cross validation.
I am trying to understand the difference between cut-off and horizon parameters but it is a bit confusing to begin with.
Link - https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/diagnostics.html#cross-validation
Here is what I would like to implement -
Fold 1 -
train = 2022-01-01 to 2022-12-31 (1 year)
test = 2023-01-01 to 2023-12-31
Fold 2 -
train = 2022-01-01 to 2023-12-31 (add 3 months)
test = 2023-04-01 to 2023-03-31
I tried giving custom cut-off dates as below but I did not understand how much data is used for training and how much is used for validation
cutoffs = pd.to_datetime(['2023-01-01','2023-03-01'])
df_cv = cross_validation(m, cutoffs=cutoffs, horizon='365 days')

Also the output seems to have horizon beginning from 36 days onwards which seems confusing.

I would want the k-fold to set up something like below - 
